# Time required to get results by solar radiation tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, performance, solar-radiation

How much does time does the ArcGIS solar radiation tool take to give solar map for day of about 50 km area?

Answer (score 6):

That depends on you data resolution and computer specifications including RAM and processing power. It took me about 1-day to do a college campus at about 2m resolution.

I cannot link to GeoNet as it is behind a log in wall but on this forum I found that,

"We are using the tool to calculate direct and diffuse incoming solar radiation for a valley in the mountains. The cell size of the raster is 1 m x 1 m and it has around 45'000 columns by 42'000 rows - it's quite big.
We try to calculate the radiation for the period of a whole year with a time interval of 14 days and 0.5 hours. The output will be a single file."

This took about 1 month on a high spec PC.

Comment: i have core i7 with 8 Gb ram

Comment: How many rows and colomns?

Comment: sorry i am new to this i got the DEM from teacher any idea where to look for in arc info for rows and columns?

Comment: arccatalog, right click > Properties

Comment: 2138 columns,1919 rows

Comment: It is impossible to give you an exact answer as machine specs differ so much and running out of RAM and moving to a paging file or similar makes such a difference. Ditto for software version but...using simple logic your process is 0.2% of the one I cite so you would expect it to take 14 hours +- a huge amount of uncertainty

Comment: well i am using ARCGIS 10

Comment: thank u soo much for answering and putting up with all my questions